# Applying Draft Wysiwyg in React Hooks Project

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, draftjs

I try to integrate [react draft wysiwyg](https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg) in my React Hooks project.

I initialize **description** this way:

```
var editorState = EditorState.createEmpty()
const [description, setDescription] = React.useState(editorState);
```

...and I apply editor this way:

```
<Editor
    editorState={description}
    toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
    wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
    editorClassName="editorClassName"
    onEditorStateChange={setEditorState}
/>
```

This is setEditorState:

```
const setEditorState = (editorState) => {
  console.log('editorState', editorState)
  setDescription(editorState)
}
```

As I type on the editor, **description** is not what I type, but instead an object like this:

```
_immutable: {allowUndo: true,…}
```

**UPDATE 1**
I also found that current content is what I type. Is it proper way to access data like this?

```
_immutable.currentContent.text
```

**UPDATE 2**
I also tried to set editor state **directly** like this, but didn't help:

```
onEditorStateChange={setDescription}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I solved this by converting to/from html.

This is enough to convert editor state to html.

```
import {stateToHTML} from 'draft-js-export-html';
....

let html = stateToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent());
```

and when I convert html back to editor state, I apply as in the [documentation](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs).

```
const html = props.content;
const contentBlock = htmlToDraft(html);
if (contentBlock) {
  const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlock.contentBlocks);
  editorStateInitial = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
}

const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(editorStateInitial);
```

This conversion circle solves the problems.